# Wordpress Migration Issue

Tags: wordpress, migration

I have a WordPress site that works fine on my local machine. However, when I try to migrate it to my domain (copy the files and import the DB and change the DB info in wp-config), it only shows the installer and not the site itself. Is there anything that can cause such an error?

Comment: Did you migrate the database before importing it and did you set the correct prefix and name in the wp-config.php file?

Comment: did it before and after and had the same issue the prefix should be the same because the db was imported via sql dumb @drip

Comment: installer? What plugin you use to migrate the site? Could you provide the screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

if you import DB to server host, probably you must to change options on database tables,
Ex.: "localhost" to "serveraddress"

LOOK THIS ARTICLE:
http://torquemag.io/2016/02/move-wordpress-from-localhost-to-live-server/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your database has the localhost links in the database. There is a library to replace old links to new in your wp database.
download this [Library](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) and place it in your wordpress folder where wp-config file is placed and replace your localhost link like http://localhost/wordpress to new link http://exampledomain.com and press live run this will replace all the links in the database to new links